# How to fetch Sidekiq job from deadset using argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

Hi I want to fetch job from sidekiq deadset 
I tried using `jobs = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new`
but this will give all the dead jobs, can we do something to fetch particular job which have certain argument.
suppose my sidekiq job was XYZWorker [1,2,3] with these three argument, so I want to fetch this job from deadset and retry it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a deadset, you can iterate through it and perform operations on the jobs that match your requirements:

```rb
ds = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new
    ds.select do |job|
        if job.args[0] == 1 && job.args[1] == 2 && job.args[2] == 3
        # Do something
    end
end
```